# Как проверить, верно ли равенство?

Tags: строки

Есть строка, содержащая равенство. Например:

```
2+3=5
```

Как проверить, верно ли это равенство?

Answer (score 5):

По-разному можно. Например, следующим способом можно, но не нужно делать:

```js
var s = "2+3=5";
console.log(s.match(/^[-+=0-9]+$/) && eval(s.replace(/=/g, "===")) === true);
```

Comment: `eval` на пользовательский ввод выглядит _подозрительно_.

Comment: @VladD, во-первых, там написано, что так делать не надо, а во-вторых, из плюсов, минусов, цифр и знаков равенства вроде ничего вредного не получается - сначала же проверка по регулярке.

Comment: А, точно, ну с регуляркой по идее покатит, да.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите практически любую книгу с олимпиадныи задачами по программированию, там есть такая задача.

Суть в том, что Вы сначала проверяете минимальную систему счисления, для которой все цифры в равенстве подходят - здесь это будет 6. Далее можете в самом простом случае в проверять последовательно с/с с большим основанием. Чтобы избежать полного перебора, попробуйте проанализировать, что переходит в старший разряд (в случае сложения), например для десятичной с/с 7+6 = 13, в следующий разряд перейдет 1, в данном - останется 3. Тут можно получить набор допустимых с/с. Далее получаем для каждого разряда такие наборы и находим общее покрытие.